# Passing two parameters in CommandParameter in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined a model as follows:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Transport> TransportModel { get; set; }
}
```

Based on the above model, I have instantiated a list that contains hard coded values for testing purposes.

Further, I am dynamically populating buttons based on the TransportModel values on a XAML page as follows:

```
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout();

        foreach (var t in user.TransportModel)
        {
// Here I am looping to access data in the TransportModel
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = t.Name;
            btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("ShowCommandParameter"));
            btn.CommandParameter = user.TransportModel; // if this correct ?
            stack.Children.Add(btn);
        }
```

And I have the following ViewModel:

```
 public TransportViewModel()
        {
            ShowCommandParameter = new Command<UserDetails>(Show);
        }

        public void Show(UserDetails param)
        {
        // I want to access properties of TransportModel here..
        }
```

The issue that I am having is that I want to pass two parameters in the `CommandParameter`. And I want to access these values within the `Show` method.

Could someone please help me on this ? I'm totally stuck.

Comment: you should only need to pass a UserDetails object as the parameter, it has all of the data you need

Comment: @Jason : Is this correct :   `btn.CommandParameter = t;` ?

Then how do I access it within the method `Show` ?

Comment: I spoke too soon, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since each button only applies to a specific `Transport`, you want to pass a `Transport` object as your `CommandParameter`

```
foreach (var t in user.TransportModel)
{
  ...
  btn.CommandParameter = t;
  ...
}
```

then

```
    public TransportViewModel()
    {
        ShowCommandParameter = new Command<Transport>(Show);
    }

    public void Show(Transport param)
    {
        // param contains the selected Transport
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a tons brother. You are always helpful :)